# Организация базы данных системы агрегатор

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, postgresql

Как организовать БД для системы которая сравнивает цены одного товара в нескольких супермаркетах. Как e-katalog. Например, есть продукт 'А' и этот продукт продается в нескольких супермаркетах с разными ценами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. В первой таблице товары (артикулы).
2. Во второй - супермаркеты.
3. В третьей - связи между первой и второй (артикул, маркет, цена).

Таблицы с категориями, опциями, характеристиками, остатками добавить по вкусу))

Answer (score 1):

Лучше создать одну таблицу, в которой создать id для каждого супермаркета и добавлять цены с парсера, сравнивая и выводя необходимые.
Так-же в нее добавить и остальные необходимые опции. Например, как организовано здесь: https://supermarkets.com.ua/
Так не нужно будет посылать запросы по нескольким таблицам, собирая данные, что уменьшит нагрузку на MySQL сервер.